# How to execute xpdf (pdftotext.exe) on shared drive?

Tags: php, cmd, exec, pdftotext, xpdf

im trying to parse **pdf** to **text** via `PHP` and `XPDF` (pdftotext.exe). On my localhost everythings works well, but when im trying to move everything on server, im getting into troubles.

First of all i checked some settings on server and safe_mode is **off**, **exec** is not disabled and permissions are `rwxrwxrwx`.

Then im trying this

```
$command = "\\\\149.223.22.11\\cae\\04_Knowledge-base\\tools\\pdftotext.exe -enc UTF-8 ". $fileName . " \\\\149.223.22.11\\cae\\04_Knowledge-base\\output.txt";


$result = exec($command,$output,$args);
echo shell_exec($command);
```

which isnt working. When i look into `$result, $output,` are empty, but $args returns 1 which coresponds to *Incorrect function* by this document [windows system error codes](http://www.hiteksoftware.com/knowledge/articles/049.htm)

Whole command looks like `\\149.223.22.11\cae\04_Knowledge-base\tools\pdftotext.exe -enc UTF-8 \\149.223.22.11\cae\04_Knowledge-base\testpdf\04_egerland_final_paper.pdf \\149.223.22.11\cae\04_Knowledge-base\output.txt` and when is dirrectly inputed into commandline, its working.

So im a bit out of ideas. Have someone any hint?

edit 20160201 - aditional trying
So i made aditional tests and when im trying to run similar command with exec from localhost (target .exe file, input and output file is in same location, only im using localhost not server) its working. Im now checking differences in server settings. So can here be problem, that localhosts Server Api is **Apache 2.0** Handler and server is **CGI/FASTCGI**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was all mistake on my side. I badly checked IIS permissions and forgot to assign user to virtual directory which i wana to access. So my only advice and more wisdom from this is to double (maybe triple) check if you have all permissions set correctly.