# How to set users permissions with IIS7 to access network drive directory

Tags: php, permissions, iis-7, file-permissions, user-permissions

for first mention, this question is extension to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063675/how-to-execute-xpdf-pdftotext-exe-on-shared-drive).
And my goal is still same. I have IIS7 server (where i running some PHP) on network drive (drive 1), when im trying acces another network drive (drive 2), where are need to acces PDF files with **pdftotext.exe**.

On drive 1 i also have a virtual/link directory (virDir) on directory (tarDir) on drive 2 when all files i need to acces are stored.

When i run pdftotext.exe by myself everything work like a charm, on drive 1 output file with pdfcontent is created and everyone lives happy till dead. But when im trying to execute PHP script, stored in drive 1 in virDir, which runs **pdftotext.exe** via exec command, it returns 1 and no file is created.

In my last question i figured out that it will be probably permission issue, but im bit confused how to set them. IIS7 have some internal users like IUSR and IIS_IUSRS and when i call `get_current_user();` in php, its set to testUser.

So which permissions i need to set to both dirs(virDir and tarDir) so server can acces them?

I tried that testUser have set Modify, Read a Execute, List folder contents, Read, Write permissions on tarDir (drive 2), and IUSR, testUser and II_IUSRS have Read a Execute, List folder contents, Read, Write permissions on tarDir (drive 1).

When im trying to acces "normal" files, like txt, pptx, etc i can read them without problem (im using php library for it), but when i try to use pdftotext.exe it fails.

Can someone see what im doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
So i made some other testing, and when i run this comand (im currious who is running command line)

```
echo "<br> who am i in command line? <br>";
$out = array();
exec('cmd /c whoami 2>&1',$out,$exitcode);
echo "<br />EXEC: ( exitcode : $exitcode )";
echo "<hr /><pre>";
print_r($out);
echo "</pre>";
```

Runned on drive 1 it shows that command line is runned by testUser, but when i run it in drive 1 virDir, it returns 1. So probably issue with permissions about executing commands in shell... i will apreaciaty any hint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems issue wasnt in permissions (i set permisions for both directories to testUser, and still getting same error), but when i moved pdftotext.exe to virtual directory, and now it looks like it working. But im curious why...

Answer (score 0):

Use the permission as "Everyone", so that directory can be accessed without  any issues.

Steps:

1. right click on directory folder and select properties
2. Under Security tab click the Edit button
3. Now click Add button
4. Specify "Everyone" in the field: Enter the object name to select and click check names to recognize it.
5. Give Full Control and Apply

Recently i faced the same issue, the above step solved it